# VS Code on Windows: How can I compile a Node/Linux project?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I cloned the [WebPack Docks](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org) repository. Now, when I open that repository in Visual Studio Code, I want to run the NPM script `build` from that repository. Yet, that doesn't work because the `build` script uses `sh`.

So, I installed WSL and an Umbuntu distribution, hoping that's the right direction to go.

Now, how can I have VS Code (on Windows) utilize the Linux dist to run NPM scripts, without me being required to mirror all NPM development tools to the Linux OS which I already have installed on Windows.

Comment: Could you make your question more clear, I'm getting the sense that you already have a solution.

Comment: Hopefully that's not the solution you seem to suggest. I'm actually expecting somehow that `sh`, `bash` and stuff are just made available from within Windows. Otherwise WSL wouldn't make sense. If I'd have to install everything to Linux, then why shouldn't I simply set up a VM? All the efforts going into WSL wouldn't legitimate the result then.